# Compillation problem of extensions in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm-package

This error is in vuejs, I tried many things but couldn't solve the error:

[image: image description]

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 39:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './views/ResetPassword' in 
'D:\office project\New folder\04-restaurant\resources\js'
Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? 
Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json"]' instead of 
'["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json"]'?
```

This error is encountered after I run the compile command as `npm run watch` in vuejs so wants to compile without error.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. If someone can provide the solution, would be very thankful to them.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this today myself.

Make sure .vue() is included in webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .<sass and other js, etc...>
```