# Laravel Mix Vue Page showing Blank

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

When I am running `npm run dev` or `npm run production`, I am getting an error that the Vue file does not have loaders defined.

I resolved this by using this resouce:
[Compillation problem of extensions in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76338375/compillation-problem-of-extensions-in-vuejs)

I used `.vue` in my `webpack.mix.js`.

Here is the example:

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue();
```

This enabled `npm run dev` to compile, but after compilation my Vue page got blank and this error is showing in console:

[image: Console error message]

Laravel Version is 10
Node Version is 16
Laravel-mix version is 6.0.49

Comment: You need to fix the errors from the console. If you click on the file and line numbers (like `app.js:4618` then you will be directed to the part of your code that is causing an error. You can paste that part of the code in your question if you want us to help fix it.

Comment: @BritishWerewolf This issue has been fixed in my app.js i have changed vue import from ```window.Vue = require("vue")``` TO ```window.Vue = require("vue").default;``` and now its working fine

Comment: Which VueJs version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved now we have to change vue import in app.js file
From
`window.Vue = require("vue");`
TO
`window.Vue = require("vue").default;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).